# Vue.js keyup events and v-model length on Android not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keyup

On Android the length of v-model is returning 0 on keyup unless its a number or the space bar key. Does anyone know why that is and how to make it fire the keyup event no matter what key it is and get the length? Here is a cleaned up version of what I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="typeahead">
    <input
      v-model="query"
      v-on:keyup="suggestTerms"
      >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      query: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    suggestTerms () {
      console.log('query length = ' + this.query.length);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

P.S. This works on every browser and device except Android.

Comment: It's a vue "feature". See this https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8231 and this https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8723

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There have been instances when v-model didn't update on mobile in **some cases**. [Issue on Forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-model-not-working-on-chrome-android-or-iphone-safari/39268) (current), [Another from Forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-model-not-working-on-chrome-browser-on-android-device/36364)

You can also code the v-model explicitly, it works in both android and pc.

```js
function callMe(){
    var vm = new Vue({
        el : '#root',
        data : {query : ''},
        methods: {
          suggestTerms () {
            console.log('query length = ' + this.query.length);
          }
        }
    })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <h3>Decomposed</h3>
  <div>
    <input type='text' :value='query' @input='evt=>query=evt.target.value' v-on:keyup="suggestTerms">
    
    <b>{{query}}({{query.length}})</b>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick. I can't thank you enough. I spent a couple days trying many different ways around this and came up short every time. Cheers.

Comment: @nunya if this solved your issue, could you accept it as the answer? This will help future readers who have similar questions/problems find the solution easier.

Comment: Yikes - 2021 and this is still an issue! how is that possible. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I'm trying on Android (chrome and edge) and it's not working even with this answer. The model is filled only if input loses focus (if I click outside of it)

Comment: @madsongr maybe you're using onchange instead of oninput?

Comment: @RonenTeva Hi. I made some changes and it's working as the answer above. Thanks!